# finding referenced library from import statement in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have a Java project in Eclipse with quite a lot of third-party libraries. Now I am looking for a way to get from the import statement to the corresponding .jar in my "Referenced Libraries" section.

My import statements look like this:

```
import org.xml.sax.*;
```

Currently, to find out which .jar this came from, I need to open them all (in the Eclipse Package Explorer) and check which of them contains this path of org/xml etc. This is quite annyoing, so I am wondering if there is a better way? Can I

1. improve my imports to make them more readable?
2. somehow "jump" from the import statement to the referenced .jar with some nice Eclipse method?

I tried to find some information on this in the www, but either there is none or my search terms were wrong.

Comment: Ctrl+click on the 'import class name' will get you to the jar

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such method. You import only those jars which are necessary for your application and when you do, you know which jar has which packages etc... To improve imports to make them more readable, do not import with * at all.

Comment: Madhan, it will take you the class not jar.

Comment: @Madhan, this seems to work only with some Java core class and my own ones, but not with referenced jars.

Comment: @Madhan, sorry, the same as below is true for ctrl+click: Only works without *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open a class file (one way is to press <kbd>F3</kbd> on the class) you can then use 'Show In > Package Explorer' (or 'Project Explorer') in the right-click menu to show the class in the explorer view - the view will then show you which jar contains the class.

Comment: When I put the cursor somewhere on the import statement and press F3 I get a red text saying "current text selection cannot be opened in an editor".

Comment: You can't do this for * type imports. You need to press F3 on an actual class name.